# Can the default location of an Orchard CMS module be changed?

Tags: orchardcms

I'm setting up an Orchard CMS project with the intention of creating a module to house my MVC 3 application.  This application has already been started and has 5 projects already.  One web project, some test projects and a workflow project.

Requiring that the web project (and therefore the other 4 projects for simplicity) lives within /Orchard.Web/Modules/ is a minor inconvenience - is it possible to change where Orchard looks (or add a new location) when dynamically loading the modules?

It's not a massive deal, but a nice to have for this project.

In an ideal world i'd be able to have:

```
/OrchardStuff/Orchard.Web
/OrchardStuff/etc
/MyStuff/MyProj.Web
/MyStuff/MyProj.Tests
```

I know i can arrange my sln in a nice usable way, would be nice if i could replicate this in the file system.

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wouldn't be easier to add an afterBuild task in your web project to copy the application to the Orchard's modules directory?

Something like that in the csproj file would do the trick (sort of, I am not entirely sure of my syntax. :'( )

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
  <ItemGroup>
  <AppFiles Include="**\*.*"/>
  </ItemGroup>
  <Copy SourceFiles="@(AppFiles)"
        DestinationFiles="@(AppFiles->'..\OrchardStuff\Orchard.Web\Modules\MyModule\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)')" />

</Target>
```

The MSDN documentation is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3e54c37h.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The solution I used is adding the following line to post-build operation:

```
if not exist "$(SolutionDir)..\Orchard\src\Orchard.Web\Modules\$(ProjectName)" mklink /D "$(SolutionDir)..\Orchard\src\Orchard.Web\Modules\$(ProjectName)" ""$(ProjectDir)"
```

This command creates a symlink of your dev folder inside Orchard's Modules folder (only if such symlink doesn't already exist).

It has the following advantages over @Eilistraee's answer:

1. If you change Javascript/CSS file in your dev machine, you don't need to build the project to get the changes into Orchard.
2. You don't get duplicate files on your drive
3. Post-build is a more explicit option and the macro variables make it easy to copy to any new module.

Answer (score 0):

No that's not possible without some major efforts. Not worth it.

Comment: thanks for the quick response - do you see any problems with Eilistraee's idea above?

Comment: Eilistraee's idea is the one already used in the Orchard.Azure solution: there, modules need to be in the Orchard.Azure.Web/Modules folder, so they get copied from the Azure.Web/Modules in a comppilation task. It works there, so it should also work for your case :)